# byte to string "decimal point is a problem"

Tags: c#

This code is written in C# dot net

i am receiving DATA in below mention format
49 46 48 50 which is equivalent to 1.02 in decimal format
using this simple code

```
DATA = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
```

later i add DATA in a buffer

```
buffer[byte_count++] = DATA;   // byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
```

Now with 49 46 48 50 DATA byte value

```
buffer[1] contains 49
buffer[2] contains 46
buffer[3] contains 48
buffer[4] contains 50
```

problem is the decimal point
i can convert 49 to 1 by simple subtracting byte value from 48
but how could i convert 46 into the decimal point and save all bytes into an strings

really very appreciate if any one can solve my problem
Ashraf

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the data is ASCII use (UPDATE as per comment):

```
string MyString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (buffer, 1, 4);
```

MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Comment: This will try to decode the entire buffer, include the one unused byte at the beginning and the 251 unused bytes after the data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Encoding` class:

```
string value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 1, 4);
```

Note: You have placed the data in the array starting from 1, but array indexes are zero based, so you need to specify the offset and length in the `GetString` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytes = { 49, 46, 48, 50 };
            //get string
            string str = new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes));
            Console.WriteLine(str);

            //get number
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(str, out d))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }

        }
    }
}
```